# how to fix the problem 'Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker'

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipbjo.png)I am using Linux shell to run python code. When I scrawl the web using beautifulsoup, it shows  'Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker', I cannot get the information. I tried to change headers, but no effect. how to fix it?

Comment: You need to use Selenium WebDriver to execute JavaScript.

Comment: Please add some code to your question. Otherwise it is difficult to understand the exact issue you are facing :)